# android alarmManager ignore my notifications

Tags: android, time, notifications, delay, alarmmanager

I have a problem about AlarmManager.
I know how to show a notification at specific time (I already do that) but a "mistake" appears when I create more notifications

the method createNotifications() it's called in onCreate method of Start Activity and the purpose of this method is to create some notification in some different time.
When App run show only the first notification at the last time.

I not use the setRepeating method of AlarmManager because I need to create notifications with different delay and with different title and description

```
    public void createNotifications(){
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        long when = startTime + (i+1)*4000;
        System.out.println("creating intent at "+when);
        String title = "title of "+i;
        String description = "description of "+i;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Receiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("title",title);  //title and description are read from receiver and service
        intent.putExtra("description",description);
        PendingIntent pI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, when, pI);
    }
}
```

Android show me a notification with title:"title of 0",descripion:"description of 0",but appears as third notification (delay=12")